# how to convert text values ​to integer values ​on jaspersoft studio?

Tags: java, variables, groovy, jaspersoft-studio

I have data located in bdd with yes/no values that I would like to reconcile.
For that, I would like to transform my text values into an integer. Is this possible? and how?

I tested it in two functions but it still gives me the error message that one cannot make a sum of text value.
I tested by creating a variable with this function
expression: `IF((data)="Yes",1,0)`
expression initial value: `data.getValue.parseInt(Yes,1)`

and the second test is:
expression: `Integer.valueOf(IF((data)="Yes",1,0))`
initial value expression: 0

If you can help me.

Comment: please, put all the relevant code/information IN the question itself, not a link to an image, not as an image but as formatted text

Comment: this pseudocode `IF((data)="Yes",1,0)` could be represented in groovy/java as:

`(data=="Yes" ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still have an error message "the if method(boolean,object,object) in the type logicalfunction is not applicable for the argument (int).